# How do I deploy Photino.Blazor to Linux (SteamOS)?

Tags: blazor

I am trying to deploy the Photino.Blazor Hello World (from [here](https://github.com/tryphotino/photino.Blazor)) to SteamOS.  The application compiles and runs on windows.  I have attempted to publish a linux version with

```
dotnet publish -c release -r linux-x64 --self-contained -p:PublishSingleFile=True
```

However when I run this on the Steam Deck I get the following error:

```
(deck@steamdeck HelloWorld)$ ./HelloWorld 
Photino.NET: "Photino".SetTitle(Photino.Blazor App) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetUseOsDefaultLocation(False) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetWidth(1000) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetHeight(900) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetLeft(0) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetTop(100) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetIconFile(favicon.ico) 
Photino.NET: "Photino.Blazor App".SetTitle(Photino Hello World) 
Photino.NET: "Photino Hello World".Load(app://localhost/) 
Photino.NET: "Photino Hello World"*** 
Unable to load shared library 'Photino.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider se
tting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libPhotino.Native: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.Photino_ctor(PhotinoNativeParameters& parameters) 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.<WaitForClose>b__274_0() 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.Invoke(Action workItem) 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.WaitForClose() 
Error #0 
Photino.NET: "Photino Hello World".OpenAlertWindow(Fatal exception, System.ApplicationException: Native code exception. Error # 0 
See inner exception for details. 
---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'Photino.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order to help dia
gnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libPhotino.Native: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.Photino_ctor(PhotinoNativeParameters& parameters) 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.<WaitForClose>b__274_0() 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.Invoke(Action workItem) 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.WaitForClose() 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.WaitForClose() 
  at Photino.Blazor.PhotinoBlazorApp.Run() in C:\temp\delete\photino.Blazor-master\Photino.Blazor\PhotinoBlazorApp.cs:line 50 
  at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\temp\delete\photino.Blazor-master\Samples\HelloWorld\Program.cs:line 32) 
Unhandled exception. System.ApplicationException: Native code exception. Error # 0  See inner exception for details. 
---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'Photino.Native' or one of its dependencies. In order to help dia
gnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libPhotino.Native: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.Photino_ctor(PhotinoNativeParameters& parameters) 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.<WaitForClose>b__274_0() 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.Invoke(Action workItem) 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.WaitForClose() 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
  at PhotinoNET.PhotinoWindow.WaitForClose() 
  at Photino.Blazor.PhotinoBlazorApp.Run() in C:\temp\delete\photino.Blazor-master\Photino.Blazor\PhotinoBlazorApp.cs:line 50 
  at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\temp\delete\photino.Blazor-master\Samples\HelloWorld\Program.cs:line 32 
Aborted (core dumped) 
(134)(deck@steamdeck HelloWorld)$
```

I have copied all files over, including Photino.Native.so.

Comment: What you doing looks OKish...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Debian 11. I solved this problem by rebuilding Photino.Native for my system.
See https://github.com/tryphotino/photino.Blazor/issues/81